# Spring boot mongo template remove with limit query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to delete a limited set of mongo documents from a collection which have id less than 10 but want to remove them in sets of 3, so tried using limit, but it still deletes all the documents and ignores limit.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").lt(id)).limit(3);
mongoTemplate.remove(query,TestCollection.class);
```

When I perform `mongoTemplate.find(query,TestCollection.class);` limit works fine and returns 3 element at a time but in remove it doesn't works.
Is there any other way to delete in single query only.

Comment: You can try using _bulk write_ for deleting documents with the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this do it in two passes

- Find 3 ids to delete as you are doing currently
- do a `collection.remove` with `Criteria.where("_id").in[id1,id2,id3]`

I would also add a `sort` criteria before doing a limit. Otherwise the results of deletion might be dependent on the index used